# How to check when the same option is selected from a Choice box?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a choice box with multiple choices, whenever one of them is selected a different method is run. Similar to this here:

```java
        fruitChoice.valueProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            switch (newValue) {
                case "Apple":
                    System.out.println("EWWW!");
                    break;
                case "Orange":
                    System.out.println("Good choice!");
                    break;
                case "Pear":
                    System.out.println("That's OK");
                    break;
            }
        });
```

However if the user selects Apple from the dropdown while having already selected Apple, nothing is printed. I haven't seen any way to get the dropdown Node as a ListView or the Apple option as a button to manually add actions and **I can not use a Combo Box**. My current solution is as follows:

```java
        repeatChoice.showingProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue) {
                switch (repeatChoice.getValue()) {
                    case "Apple":
                        System.out.println("EWWW!");
                        break;
                    case "Orange":
                        System.out.println("Good choice!");
                        break;
                    case "Pear":
                        System.out.println("That's OK");
                        break;
                }
            }

        });
```

But this code doesn't account for ways the ChoiceBox can stop showing that don't involve selecting Apple again (such as losing focus). Is there any way of getting around this?

Comment: *"Is there any way of getting around this?"*. There's probably no elegant way. A `ChoiceBox` is designed for the user to make a selection (choice) and the API is designed so you can respond to the user selecting something. You're trying to use it for something slightly different; responding to user *actions* instead of *selections*. The correct control for this is a `MenuButton`, with a collection of `MenuItem`s. You can then register event handlers for the action events on the menu items.

Comment: I have been using Combo Boxes incorrectly. Swapping to the menu item solved my issue and they can be styled to look and behave identically to combo boxes.